# compare data types of two table columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

consider I have 2 databases A1 and A2, both have similar tables, consider T1 in A1 and T2 in A2.

I need a sql query to compare the datatypes of each column in the table, the query should return the column names which mismatch the datatypes from both the tables.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, do you only need the columns with the same name but different type? what about columns existing in only one of the two tables? And why do you say T1 ad T2? do you need to compare tables with different names? If so, how do you decide which table in DB2 should be compared with a table a DB1?

Comment: @Aleksej Yes, i was trying with below query:

Select c1.table_name,c1.COLUMN_NAME,c1.DATA_TYPE,c2.table_name,c2.DATA_TYPE,c2.COLUMN_NAME
from A1.T1 c1 Left join A2.T2 c2 on c1.COLUMN_NAME=c2.COLUMN_NAME where c1.data_type<>c2.DATA_TYPE

Comment: @Aleksej
I am using ruby code to get the list of similar tables from the 2 database. The ruby code would give me table names as follows:

["T1", "T2"]
["T3", "T4"]

where i know that these 2 tables [T1 & T2], [T3 & T4]are same from different database.

I just need a query to compare the datatype of each column in the tables.

Comment: How should the tables be compared? based on the name of columns, to check if there are columns with the same name but different type?

Comment: @Aleksej, yes, query should return columns with same name but with different data type

Comment: Either your notation or your terminology is incorrect. In Oracle, tables are not "in a database" - they are "in a schema" and the schema is "in a database." Did you mean compare similar tables in two SCHEMAS? Otherwise your notation - when you refer to tables in different databases - should include the owner (schema) to which the tables belong.

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem has a beautiful and very efficient solution - no joins, no `MINUS` operations etc., and only one pass over `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, which may be a very large table. It was first proposed by Marco Stefanelli (if I remember the name correctly) on AskTom several years ago, it was refined there and it has become the standard for table comparisons.

I don't have two different databases to play with, so I will just illustrate how I can compare tables in different schemas. You will need to adapt for your situation (you may have to read from `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` in both databases.)

In this case, we select table owner, table name, and column names, data types and other characteristics; we `GROUP BY` column name and all those column properties; and we select only the rows `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`. Indeed, if a column has the same name AND all the same characteristics in both tables, then the count will be 2 and there will be no corresponding row in the output. The output will show a row (corresponding to a column name + properties in one or both of the original tables) only if: the column name appears only in one table but not in the other; OR if the column name appears in both tables but at least one of the properties is different. Try to spot the differences in the final output below!

As you will see, in the solution I need to select `max(owner)` and `max(table_name)` - since I don't group by those columns - but in fact I select only the groups that have exactly one row, so the `max()` really has no effect.

Setup: I make a copy of the `EMP` table from the `SCOTT` schema in my own "sandbox" (a schema I created for myself, named `INTRO`). I create the copy with a CTAS - this will copy all the column names and datatypes (including size/precision/scale as the case may be), but for example it does NOT copy 'not null' constraints. So I include the `nullable` column from `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` to catch such differences. I select only the table structure, no data, by using an "always false" `WHERE` filter.

```
create table empl as select * from scott.emp where 0 is null;
Table EMPL created.

alter table empl drop column comm;
Table EMPL altered.

alter table empl add sex char(1);
Table EMPL altered.

alter table empl modify job varchar2(20);
Table EMPL altered.

alter table empl modify deptno not null;
Table EMPL altered.
```

So now I have:

```
describe scott.emp

Name     Null     Type         
-------- -------- ------------ 
EMPNO    NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
ENAME             VARCHAR2(10) 
JOB               VARCHAR2(9)  
MGR               NUMBER(4)    
HIREDATE          DATE         
SAL               NUMBER(7,2)  
COMM              NUMBER(7,2)  
DEPTNO            NUMBER(2) 


describe intro.empl

Name     Null     Type         
-------- -------- ------------ 
EMPNO             NUMBER(4)    
ENAME             VARCHAR2(10) 
JOB               VARCHAR2(20) 
MGR               NUMBER(4)    
HIREDATE          DATE         
SAL               NUMBER(7,2)  
DEPTNO   NOT NULL NUMBER(2)    
SEX               CHAR(1)
```

**Solution** (query to compare the two tables):

```
select   max(owner) as owner, max(table_name) as table_name,
         column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale, nullable
from     all_tab_columns
where    (owner = 'SCOTT' and table_name = 'EMP')
   or    (owner = 'INTRO' and table_name = 'EMPL')
group by column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale, nullable
having   count(*) = 1
order by column_name, owner, table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
OWNER TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE NULLABLE
----- ---------- ----------- --------- ----------- -------------- ---------- --------
SCOTT EMP        COMM        NUMBER             22              7          2        Y
INTRO EMPL       DEPTNO      NUMBER             22              2          0        N
SCOTT EMP        DEPTNO      NUMBER             22              2          0        Y
INTRO EMPL       EMPNO       NUMBER             22              4          0        Y
SCOTT EMP        EMPNO       NUMBER             22              4          0        N
INTRO EMPL       JOB         VARCHAR2           20                                  Y
SCOTT EMP        JOB         VARCHAR2            9                                  Y
INTRO EMPL       SEX         CHAR                1                                  Y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare a table to another, looking for columns with the same name, but different type, you can use the following.

**setup:**

```
create table t1(a number, b varchar2(16), c date, d clob);
create table t2(a number, b varchar2(99), c timestamp, d clob);
```

**query:**

```
select db1.column_name, db1.table_name, db2.table_name
from all_tab_columns db1
     inner join all_tab_columns db2
       on (db1.owner = db2.owner
           and db1.column_name = db2.column_name)       
where db1.table_name = 'T1'
  and db2.table_name = 'T2'
  and (
           db1.data_type != db2.data_type
        OR db1.data_length != db2.data_length
      ) 

COLUMN_NAME                    TABLE_NAME                     TABLE_NAME
-------------------------- -------------------------- --------------------------
B                          T1                         T2
C                          T1                         T2
```

This checks tables on the same DB; to use it across two DBs, you should have a dblink from one instance to another and replace one occurrence of `all_tab_columns` with `all_tab_columns@yourDBLink`.

Please notice that this only considers columns existing on both tables with the same name but different type; thi will not handle the case of columns with different names, or columns existing in only one table

Comment: Thanks to all for you response, but none of the query is working for my case :(..

Comment: I am using below query to compare column names in 2 different schemas:

select distinct sys_mapg_dtl_tgt_attr_nme as \"Missing Column Names\" from TEST1.V_SYS_MAPG_DTL_META where sys_mapg_dtl_tgt_attr_nme not in(   select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name ='TEST_V_UPHISTSTMTWFAUTO' and owner = 'TEST2')and sys_bld_func_nme like 'LOAD_LAN_TEST%' and sys_mapg_tgt_nme = 'TEST_V_UPHISTSTMTWFAUTO'

On the similar terms i want to have a query that can compare the column's data types.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it's not working? Please post an example of two tables to compare, with the result you need to get